# Como separar una lista con un delimitador?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como puedo hacer este ejercicio ?

"Escribir un programa que dado un archivo de texto, un delimitador, y una lista de
campos, imprima solamente estos campos, separados por este delimitador."

De momento tengo esto:

```
f=open("archivo.txt","r")
delimitador=str("-")
lista=['Hola','Adios','Hoy']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haria de esta manera:

```
f=open("archivo.txt","r")
delimitador=str("-")
lista=['Hola','Adios','Hoy']

linea = f.readline()
aImprimir = ""
primera = True

while linea != "":
    palabras = linea.split(" ")

    for palabra in palabras:
        for clave in lista:
            if clave == palabra:
                if primera:
                    aImprimir+=clave
                    primera = False

                else:
                    aImprimir+=delimitador+clave

    linea = f.readline()

print(aImprimir)
```

El problema esta en que este codigo solo funciona si el archivo leido no tiene saltos de linea, y todas las palabras tienen que estar separadas entre si por un espacio. Esto ultimo no tiene por que ser asi, con solo cambiar la linea:

```
palabras = linea.split(" ") #Entre estos parentesis lo que separe las palabras en el archivo
```